# What is returned when I do .GetItems() on a structure group?

Tags: 2011, tom.net

I understand that `.GetItems()` will return a list of items within a structure group, but exactly what items can I expect to see in that list? Will it just be pages and structure groups, or should I expect other types of items as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GetItems()` returns an `IEnumerable<RepositoryLocalObject>` which can potentially contain `Pages` and `Structure Groups`.

Adding the optional `Filter` parameter will limit the types of items returned.

Item Types can be filtered based on the below rules:

If the container is a Publication:

- ItemType.Folder (returns the root Folder)
- ItemType.StructureGroup (returns the root Structure Group, if
  present)
- ItemType.Category (returns all top-level Categories, if any exist)

If the container is a Folder:

- ItemType.Folder
- ItemType.Schema
- ItemType.Component
- ItemType.ComponentTemplate
- ItemType.PageTemplate
- ItemType.TargetGroup
- ItemType.TemplateBuildingBlock
- ItemType.VirtualFolder

If the container is a Virtual Folder:

- ItemType.Folder
- ItemType.Schema
- ItemType.Component
- ItemType.ComponentTemplate
- ItemType.PageTemplate
- ItemType.TargetGroup
- ItemType.TemplateBuildingBlock
- ItemType.VirtualFolder
- ItemType.StructureGroup
- ItemType.Page

If the container is a Structure Group:

- ItemType.StructureGroup
- ItemType.Page

If the container is a Category:

- ItemType.Category
- ItemType.Keyword

‏

Comment: Virtual Folder can also contain Pages and Structure Groups, since it is a search result.

Answer (score 4):

You will received just the items that can be created inside a Structure Group, `Pages` and `Structure Groups`